# How to add Crashlytics to the new architecture sample by Google

Tags: android, firebase, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am starting a new project by using the architecture-templates by google (https://github.com/android/architecture-templates)

In this template, they use Gradle with Kotlin DSL. I am trying to add Crashlytics to this project but the structure of gradle is quite different from my old projects.

I am stuck on the step 2 of the base guide ([Firebase Get Started Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=0#add-plugin))

> Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version:
> '7.3.1']
>
> > The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so
> > compatibility cannot be checked.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found that the architecture template is based on gradle 7.6 which use the version catalog feature.

So I based my Version Catalog file on this https://github.com/RedMadRobot/gradle-version-catalogs/blob/main/versions-stack/libs.versions.toml

Now my build.gradle.kts file is

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle)
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlitycs)
    alias(libs.plugins.gms.googleServices)
}

....

dependencies {

implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to be confused about this too, but after some tries, I found the correct answer.
I think this is the first point of step 2 where you are confused. Just add the following code at the top of the project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
```

Just follow the Google guide for the rest.

Complete code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Edited:**

DSL version:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.10" apply false
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

This website([Gradle Kotlinize - Groovy to Kotlin converter online](https://gradle-kotlinize.web.app/)) may be able to help you.

Comment: this is not gradle with kotlin dsl

Comment: @appersiano I missed the DSL, the DSL version has been added